# How can I loop through this ruby array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying the following code however in the console it just returns the entire microposts array. I want to get the tag_list for each micropost that a user has posted.

As in I want User.find(1).microposts[0..-1].tag_list

```
User.find(1).microposts.each {|micropost| micropost.tag_list}
```

How can I get the tag_list for all posts?

Sorry for the noob question

Comment: I deleted my answer cause it was wrong. Good luck :)

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire thanks for the taking time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
User.find(1).microposts.map(&:tag_list).flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
User.find(1).microposts.map(&:tag_list)
```